# Capacitor iOS Using Cookie Based Auth

Tags: ios, cookies, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am using Capacitor v3, NextJS static export, and a Django backend to build out an iOS app based on a production website.

The current backend authentication scheme uses Django sessions via cookies as well as setting the CSRF token via cookies. The CSRF token can be bypassed pretty easily for the app and not worried about disabling that but forking our authentication scheme would be somewhat of a hassle. The [capacitor-community/http](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http) claims to allow Cookies but I haven't been able to configure that correctly.

Capacitor Config:

```js
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.nextwebapp.app',
  appName: 'nextwebapp',
  webDir: 'out',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};

export default config;
```

Note that I have tried setting `server.hostname` to `myapp.com` as well.

Based on the comments at the bottom of the [capacitor http readme](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http#third-party-cookies-on-ios) I set the following Info.plist values.

App/Info.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
....
    <key>WKAppBoundDomains</key>
    <array>
        <string>staging.myapp.com</string>
        <string>myapp.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The web app uses a [react hooks wrapper package for axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks) so in order to keep changes minimal I made a hook that mimics the state returned from that package.

hooks/useNativeRequest.ts

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Http } from "@capacitor-community/http";

import {
  BASE_URL,
  DEFAULT_HEADERS,
  HOST_NAME,
  ERROR_MESSAGE,
  Refetch,
  RequestOptions,
  ResponseValues,
  RequestConfig,
} from "@utils/http";
import { handleResponseToast } from "@utils/toast";

const makeUrl = (url): string => `${BASE_URL}${url}`;

const getCSRFToken = async () =>
  await Http.getCookie({ key: "csrftoken", url: HOST_NAME });

const combineHeaders = async (headers: any) => {
  const newHeaders = Object.assign(DEFAULT_HEADERS, headers);
  const csrfHeader = await getCSRFToken();

  if (csrfHeader.value) {
    newHeaders["X-CSRFToken"] = csrfHeader.value;
  }

  return newHeaders;
};

function useNativeRequest<T>(
  config?: RequestConfig,
  options?: RequestOptions
): [ResponseValues<T>, Refetch<T>] {
  const [responseState, setResponseState] = useState({
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
  });

  let method = "get";
  let url = config;
  let headers = {};
  let params = undefined;
  let data = undefined;
  if (config && typeof config !== "string") {
    url = config.url;
    method = config.method?.toLowerCase() ?? method;
    headers = config.headers;
    params = config.params;
    data = config.data;
  }

  const requestMethod = Http[method];

  const makeRequest = async () => {
    setResponseState({ error: null, data: null, loading: true });

    try {
      const reqHeaders = await combineHeaders(headers);
      console.log({
        url,
        reqHeaders,
        params,
        data
      })
      const response = await requestMethod({
        url: makeUrl(url),
        headers: reqHeaders,
        params,
        data,
      });

      if (response?.status === 200) {
        setResponseState({ error: null, data: response.data, loading: false });
        handleResponseToast(response?.data?.detail);
      } else {
        const errorMessage = response?.data?.detail || ERROR_MESSAGE;
        handleResponseToast(errorMessage);
        setResponseState({
          error: errorMessage,
          data: response.data,
          loading: false,
        });
      }

      return response;
    } catch {
      setResponseState({
        error: ERROR_MESSAGE,
        data: null,
        loading: false,
      });

      return Promise.reject(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!options?.manual) {
      makeRequest();
    }
  }, [options?.manual]);

  return [responseState, makeRequest];
}

export { useNativeRequest };
```

The `console.log` above never includes the additional csrf cookie and in the getter logs it doesn't contain a value.

Backend Django

```py
    MIDDLEWARE = [
      ...
      'myapp_webapp.middle.CustomCSRFMiddleWare',
    ]
    
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
        ...
        "capacitor://localhost",
    ]

   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
      'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
      ),
    }
```

middleware

```py
class CustomCSRFMiddleWare(CsrfViewMiddleware):

    def process_request(self, request):
        # Special Processing for API Requests
        if "/api/v1" in request.path:
            try:
                requested_with = request.headers['X-Requested-With']
                myapp_request = request.headers['X-Myapp-Request']

                # Check Custom Headers
                if not (requested_with == 'XMLHttpRequest' and myapp_request == '1'):
                    raise PermissionDenied()

                return None

            except KeyError:
                # All API Requests should include the above headers
                raise PermissionDenied()

        
        # Call original CSRF Middleware
        return super(CustomCSRFMiddleWare, self).process_request(request)
```

Occasionally the backend will also show that `X-Requested-With` is not being sent but it is included in the `DEFAULT_HEADERS` constant I have in the UI and appears in the console.log.

Is anything above preventing me from being able to read and send cookies from Capacitor on iOS? Does Cookie based authentication even work with capacitor?

Comment: What is the question here?  Is it "how to send cookies with capacitor?"  how to send http headers?  Can you replicate this with a *simple* command line script, e.g. `http post -v localhost:8000 X-Header:value .....` to help find what part is actually not doing the thing that is expected

Comment: the question is how to send cookies with capacitor on iOS. A command line script can't replicate the flow through the actual native http stack. 

There are a lot of posts with similar issues around the web that mostly end in "I figured it out" so I am hoping someone can write definitive steps on how to send cookies on iOS.

Comment: You seem to have a good grasp on the question, but its hard to read that from what was posted.  And what does this have to do with DRF, other than coincidentally being the backend?  Does this capacitor thread help: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-save-a-session-cookie-with-capacitor-http-plugin/205900?

Comment: @Andrew yea fair point about DRF. I removed that tag just wanted to make sure the complete picture was here. Hopefully once I have this working I can make a blog post of full stack django, next, capacitor app.

I have tried that solution but it doesn't seem to have any impact from what I can see.

Comment: I believe I have this working now. Drafting up an updated version of my code samples as an answer. After a lot of keyboard bashing was able to get the Http plugin working against a stock Django session based auth backend.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my updated react hook that combine's my above question and [thread mentioned](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-save-a-session-cookie-with-capacitor-http-plugin/205900) in the comments as well as some manual cookie setting.

The below client side code worked without changes to existing Django Session authentication.

The changes from my code above

- Added `credentials: "include"` to `webFetchExtra`
- Added `"Content-Type": "application/json"` to headers
- Handle override of the initial config for manual request & refetch
- Set Session Cookie After Response
- Based on the docs this shouldn't be necessary but I am keeping in my code for now.

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import { Http } from "@capacitor-community/http";

const DEFAULT_HEADERS = {
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "X-MyApp-Request": "1",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

const makeUrl = (url): string => `${BASE_URL}${url}`;

const getCSRFToken = async () =>
  await Http.getCookie({ key: "csrftoken", url: HOST_NAME });

const setSessionCookie = async () => {
  const sessionId = await Http.getCookie({ key: "sessionid", url: HOST_NAME });

  if (sessionId.value) {
    await Http.setCookie({
      key: "sessionid",
      value: sessionId.value,
      url: HOST_NAME,
    });
  }
};

const combineHeaders = async (headers: any) => {
  const newHeaders = Object.assign(DEFAULT_HEADERS, headers);
  const csrfHeader = await getCSRFToken();

  if (csrfHeader.value) {
    newHeaders["X-CSRFToken"] = csrfHeader.value;
  }

  return newHeaders;
};

const parseConfig = (config: RequestConfig, configOverride?: RequestConfig) => {
  let method = "get";
  let url = config;
  let headers = {};
  let params = undefined;
  let data = undefined;

  if (config && typeof config !== "string") {
    url = config.url;
    method = config.method ?? method;
    headers = config.headers;
    params = config.params;
    data = config.data;
  }

  return {
    url,
    method,
    headers,
    params,
    data,
    ...(configOverride as AxiosRequestConfig),
  };
};

function useNativeRequest<T>(
  config?: RequestConfig,
  options?: RequestOptions
): [ResponseValues<T>, Refetch<T>] {
  const [responseState, setResponseState] = useState({
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
  });

  const makeRequest = useCallback(
    async (configOverride) => {
      setResponseState({ error: null, data: null, loading: true });
      const { url, method, headers, params, data } = parseConfig(
        config,
        configOverride
      );

      try {
        const reqHeaders = await combineHeaders(headers);
        const response = await Http.request({
          url: makeUrl(url),
          headers: reqHeaders,
          method,
          params,
          data,
          webFetchExtra: {
            credentials: "include",
          },
        });

        if (response?.status === 200) {
          setResponseState({
            error: null,
            data: response.data,
            loading: false,
          });
          await setSessionCookie();
        } else {
          setResponseState({
            error: errorMessage,
            data: response.data,
            loading: false,
          });
        }

        return response;
      } catch {
        setResponseState({
          error: ERROR_MESSAGE,
          data: null,
          loading: false,
        });

        return Promise.reject(ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }
    },
    [config]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!options?.manual) {
      makeRequest(config);
    }
  }, [options?.manual]);

  return [responseState, makeRequest];
}

export { useNativeRequest };
```